# python: search for a duplicate user input and print result

Tags: python, duplicates

hi I am trying to make this code work, I think it's self explanitary what i'm trying to do.

```
def f():
 ri = raw_input('enter a number 1-100')
 a = range(1, 100, 2)
 if ri in a: print 'duplicate'
 if ri not in a: print 'not duplicate'
```

please can you help me to make it work!

Answer (score 1):

You are checking for a string instead a range (which is a list of `ints`). Try:

```
if int(ri) in a
```

You can also change your second `if` into an `else`.

Comment: thanks, I am just learning python at trypython.org, so I needed to say that ri was an int. ok. thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

Problem is that this doesn't actually check for 'duplicate' for any worthwhile interpretation of duplicate.

The above answer is correct as to why your code 'doesn't work' - this would 'work':

```
def f():
 ri = raw_input('enter a number 1-100')
 a = range(1, 100, 2)
 print 'duplicate' if int(ri) in a else 'not duplicate'
```

What do you really mean by duplicate though?

Comment: Thanks for the answers guys: I mean if the user input is already in a, then it is a duplicate.